# Compute the sums of the rows and columns of a two dimensional array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I tried to get the sum of the rows and columns of a two dimensional array, but the result is 0. I don't know what my mistake is. Thank you for you help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int characters[50][50],rc,sum=0,horizontal[10]={0},vertical[10]={0},c,r;
   
    cout<<"Please enter integer : ";
    cin>>rc;
    cout <<" The matrix is : \n";
   
    for(r=0;r<rc;r++){
        for( c=0;c<rc;c++){
            sum=sum+1;
            characters[r][c]=sum;
            cout<<characters[r][c]<< " ";
            horizontal[r]=horizontal[r]+characters[r][c];
            vertical[c]=vertical[c]+characters[c][r];
        }
           
        cout<< "The sum of horizontal is = " <<horizontal[r]<<" and The sum of vertical is "<<vertical[c];;
        cout<<endl;
   }
   
   return 0;
}
```

This is the result of this code

```
Please enter integer : 3

    The matrix is : 
    1 2 3 The sum of horizontal is = 6 and The sum of vertical is 0
    4 5 6 The sum of horizontal is = 15 and The sum of vertical is 0
    7 8 9 The sum of horizontal is = 24 and The sum of vertical is 0
```

Comment: `vertical[i]=vertical[i]+characters[c][r];` -> `characters[c][r];` is used uninitialized.

Comment: is that meant to be a `<< vertical[i] <<` or a `<<vertical[r]<<`?

Comment: Rethink your solution: How should it be possible to print a sum of columns in each row when you have not yet looked at all rows, hm?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't compute sum of vertical before fill the matrix.
2. `vertical[c] = vertical[c] + characters[c][r]` is wrong.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string.h>
   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
      int characters[50][50],rc,sum=0,horizontal[10]={0},vertical[10]={0},c,r;

      cout<<"Please enter integer : ";
      cin>>rc;
      cout <<" The matrix is : \n";

      for(r=0;r<rc;r++){

       for( c=0;c<rc;c++){
         sum=sum+1;
         characters[r][c]=sum;
         cout<<characters[r][c]<< " ";
      }
      cout << endl;
   }

   for(r=0;r<rc;r++){

      for( c=0;c<rc;c++){
         horizontal[r]=horizontal[r]+characters[r][c];
         vertical[r] = vertical[r] + characters[c][r];

          }

          cout<< "The sum of horizontal is = " <<horizontal[r]<<" and The sum of vertical is "<<vertical[r];
          cout<<endl;

   }

   return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: He can calculate. It won't be finally calculated, but he can, please see my solution below. The only thing is the result could be printed only when the loop ends.